# Lookup word in dictionary by voice

Tags: c++, python, speech-recognition, voice, speech

I have 1000 words in 3 different dialects for the Gaelic language. I have each word in the form of three mp3 recordings. I wish to have functionality in my application, be it a website or a mobile app, which allows me to speak a word and in turn find the best match, or matches, with respect to the 1000 words.

So if I speak in the word "bheadh" I would expect to be prompted by, for example, the words  bheadh, bheidh, bheith and bith.

What is the technical term for this process?

Suppose I also wanted to lookup phrases, for example: "rud ar bith"

What reliable open source software libraries exist in this regard. I program primarily in C++ and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the technical term for this process?

Speech recognition

> What reliable open source software libraries exist in this regard. I program primarily in C++ and Python.

[CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)